# WinSock2 bind error

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, winsock2

I started making a C++ server, but I can't bind to socket.

```
#pragma once

#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <thread>

#include "Logging.h"

namespace network
{
static SOCKET sock;

static VOID startAccept()
{
    while (true)
    {
        struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
        int clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

        SOCKET accepted;

        if (accepted == NULL)
        {
            accepted = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);

            if (accepted < 0)
            {
                core::writeln("Error accept: " + WSAGetLastError());
            }
            else
            {
                core::writeln("New connection from " + cli_addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr);
            }
        }
    }
}

static VOID connect(const char* ipAddress, u_short port)
{
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (sock < 0)
    {
        core::writeln("Error creating socket: " );
        perror("error:");
        return;
    }

    else if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        core::writeln("Error binding to socket: " );
        perror("error:");
        return;
    }

    else if (listen(sock, 10) < 0)
    {
        core::writeln("Error listening socket: ");
        return;
    }

    else
    {
        core::writeln("Bound WinSock to " + serv_addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr);

        std::thread accepting(startAccept);
        accepting.join();
    }
}
};
```

In my main int:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
connect("127.0.0.1", 500);
}
```

But everytime I try to bind, I get the following output:

Error binding to socket: 
error:No Error

But the socket isn't bound on. What am  I doing  wrong?

---

FIXED, had to use WSAStartup.

Comment: Your error reporting is broken.  You've found WSAGetLastError() but you are not using it consistently, using perror() is not correct.  Fix that code and you'll now see error code 10093, WSANOTINITIALISED, "Either the application has not called WSAStartup, or WSAStartup failed".  You didn't.

Comment: WSAGetLastError indeed doesn't really work. So I'll try. Yes, now it works. Thanks :)

Comment: WSAGetLastError works fine, perror() doesn't.  Use FormatMessage() to convert the error code that WASGetLastError returns to a string.

Comment: `socket()` succeeds without calling `WSAStartup()`?